# Can't load libcrypto library in macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, openssl, homebrew, linker-errors, macos-sierra

I have an app that works fine on OSX 10.9 to 10.11, but I get the following error while trying to run the app on OSX 10.12 or higher.

I know apple stopped support of the `libcrypto.a` library in Xcode 8.0, so I had to manually install it from Homebrew, which made it work fine up to OSX 10.11.6.   This is the error I get when I run my program:

```
Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x1] Library missing

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/Pixel Perfect LED.app/Contents/MacOS/Pixel Perfect LED
  Reason: image not found

Binary Images:
       0x1010c2000 -        0x1010ebffb +com.RedDotLogicsLLC.PixelPerfectLED (1.5.0 - 1.5.0.1) <F2C668CF-3D03-3D4B-805E-7D4549E7056B> /Applications/Pixel Perfect LED.app/Contents/MacOS/Pixel Perfect LED
       0x101b06000 -        0x101b431c7  dyld (421.1) <A525EAEA-AF86-30C2-B360-3D093B4F0828> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff8309e000 -     0x7fff8309efff  com.apple.Cocoa (6.11 - 22) <5EEB0A26-F1C2-3D57-8441-52C0B80C2A6A> /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa
    0x7fff855b8000 -     0x7fff8564dfff  com.apple.framework.IOKit (2.0.2 - 1324.1.7) <10BDCD1E-0463-3C53-BF11-C9A0919C1588> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question. Try http://apple.stackexchange.com/ for help with Mac software.

Comment: well essentially its about adding library in my code that i may not have installed correctly or something ? I am not too familiar with this part in Xcode

Comment: Is the dylib located in `/usr/local/opt/opensssl/lib`?

Comment: i manually collied form one computer to the other so yes the files are now there (which i would like to get it built in to the app so i dont have to manually move it.